# Tras hacer submit en un popup y hacer insert en bbdd obtengo pagina en blanco

Tags: php, html, mysql, bootstrap

Tengo un modal que cuando le doy a Guardar me guarda en BBDD (mysql), el insert se almacena en bbdd correctamente pero obtengo pantalla en blanco cuando simplemente quiero que se cierre el modal.

Alguna idea?

Mi codigo se encuentra todo en el mismo fichero, os paso el codigo.

PHP

```
<?php

require "../db/configdb.php";

$mh = $_POST['cod_mh'];

if (isset($_POST["cod_mh"]))
{
    try 
    {
        $sql = "INSERT INTO mh(codigo_mh) VALUES ('".$_POST['cod_mh']."');";
        $result = mysql_query($sql);
        if (!$result) {
            echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
        }
    }

    catch(PDOException $error) 
    {
        echo $sql . "<br>" . $error->getMessage();
    }
    $connextion->close();
}
?>
```

HTML/BOOTSTRAP

```
<div class="modal fade" id="MHModal">
            <div class="modal-dialog">
                <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title">....</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>" method="POST">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="cod_mh" class="control-label">Código MH</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="cod_mh">
                        </div>

                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-md" id="submit_mh">Guardar</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-md" data-dismiss="modal">Salir</button>
                    </form>
                </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simplemente te falta redirigir el sitio a una ruta específica, para esto usamos [header()](http://php.net/manual/es/function.header.php):

```
<?php

require "../db/configdb.php";

$mh = $_POST['cod_mh'];

if (isset($_POST["cod_mh"]))
{
    try 
    {
        $sql = "INSERT INTO mh(codigo_mh) VALUES ('".$_POST['cod_mh']."');";
        $result = mysql_query($sql);
        if ($result) {
            header("location: ruta_de_la_pagina.html");
        }else{
            echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
        }
    }

    catch(PDOException $error) 
    {
        echo $sql . "<br>" . $error->getMessage();
    }
    $connextion->close();
}
?>
```

Comment: Hola, he probado la solución pero esto me refresca la página. El caso es que se está rellenando un formulario y tienes la opción de añadir nuevas opciones. Entonces, necesito poder volver sin refrescar...

Comment: @DavidM. entonces debes usar ajax y no método convencional !